# Reading text files in Lua

Tags: file, lua, extract

I am sorry for a duplicate post or something. I am just trying to confirm this one because I have seen similar post and did the same yet my output is not what i wanted to be the problem is to read a text file in Lua language. Here's my code:

```
   function fileExists(filename)
         file = io.open(filename, "r")
         if file == nil then
              return false
         else
              return true
         end
   end

  if fileExists ("myFile.txt") then
            print ("Hello")
  else
            print("not found")
  end
```

It keeps returning false and print not found. And also am trying to open a .lrc file instead of .txt. What is wrong with that simple, little lines of code?

Comment: instead of using `if file==nil` use `if not file then`

Comment: That is just a matter of taste, the two kinds are (almost) equivalent, although I agree the second style (`if not file then ...`) is more readable (at least to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ok, except for the file closing part:

```lua
     file = io.open(filename, "r")
     if file == nil then
          return false
     else
          file.close(file)
          return true
```

Do you really have the file `myFile.txt` in current directory?

```lua
%ls -l
-rwxr--r--  1 aef  wheel  324 23 апр 10:24 a.lua
-rw-r--r--  1 aef  wheel    0 23 апр 10:16 myFile.txt
%lua-5.1 a.lua
Hello
```

Comment: Hey What do know it finally saw my file. Andrew Filonov maybe that's what it needed all along the file.close.
By the way, i saw some post that is should be io.close(file). Is it the same?

Thanks for the reply guys. I appreciate it.

Comment: That could also be `file:close()` - this is OO syntax sugar for `file.close(file)`. If you did `local file = io.open(...)` then the Lua GC would do this for you. You set the global `file` which is available until the program ends, but in reality it should be local to `fileExists`. Although I do not feel that this should affect you simple use case in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening a `.lrc` file, and providing the filename as `.txt` it will give an error. I tried your program on a custom `.ps1` file of mine, in the parent folder to the `lua` file, and it worked fine.[image: Check for yourself]

Comment: okay so lets stick to .lrc, so I can't open .lrc files? if it worked for you fine maybe it's the file path. where should i put my file?. i tried putting it on a folder and made it like "\folder\myFile.lrc" still did not work. How do i do this?